# Compiler commands for accull while using opencv

Tags: opencv, compilation, openacc

I'm trying to accelerate an opencv program I wrote using OpenACC, I'm using the accull compiler to do this. However, I'm having a very hard time finding any documentation or examples that would help me on this issue.

http://scelementary.com/2015/04/30/openacc-on-jetson-tk1.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with ACCULL, but I can provide you with an example that uses OpenCV and OpenACC and maybe that'll help you get moving. This has been tested on X86 with PGI on Ubunut 14.04. This will read an image, invert the pixels, and write an image back out.

invert.cpp:

```
void invert(unsigned char *imgData, int w, int h, int ch, int step)
{
  int i,j,c;
#pragma acc parallel loop collapse(3) copy(imgData[:h*w*ch])
  for ( i = 0; i < h; i++)
    for ( j = 0; j < w; j++ )
      for ( c = 0; c < ch; c++ )
        imgData[i*step + j*ch + c] = 255 - imgData[i*step + j*ch + c];
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

void invert(unsigned char*,int,int,int,int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s inFilename outFilename\n",argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);

  printf("%s: %d x %d, %d %d\n", argv[1],img->width, img->height, img->widthStep, img->nChannels);

  invert((unsigned char*)img->imageData,img->width,img->height, img->nChannels, img->widthStep);

  if(!cvSaveImage(argv[2],img))
    fprintf(stderr,"Failed to write to %s.\n",argv[2]);

  cvReleaseImage(&img);

  return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
a.out: main.cpp invert.cpp
        pgc++ -fast -ta=tesla -c invert.cpp
        pgc++ -fast -ta=tesla -c main.cpp
        pgc++ -ta=tesla invert.o main.o -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using IplImage over mat?

Comment: @Zypps987 I'd converted this from a sample code and that's what the sample used. There very well may be better way to read/write the image file.